Adjust line spacing within linguex examples
I would like to set the line spacing of the whole document as 1.5 lines, including in the linguex examples. I tried to issue a \nosinglegloss in the preamble, after which the spacing between the first two lines indeed becomes the desired 1.5 lines. However, the spacing between the last (translation) and the second line seems to be unaffected.
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\linespread{1.5}
\nosinglegloss

\begin{document}\

\lipsum[1]

\exg. AaBbCcDd\\
      AaBbCcDd\\
      AaBbCcDd

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}

The above code produces the following result:


The linguex package uses a modified version of the cgloss4e glossing macros, and that package assumes that you introduce the free translation line with the \glt macro, but linguex doesn't use this. So we can modify the end of the gloss lines to add an appropriate vertical space after the gloss instead:
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\linespread{1.5}

\makeatletter
\def\gl@stop{{\hskip -\glossglue}\unhbox\gline\vspace{.25\baselineskip}\end{flushleft}%
         \global\glossfalse%
         \ifindex\expandafter\lookforwords\fi {} }
\makeatother
\nosinglegloss

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\exg. AaBbCcDd\\
      AaBbCcDd\\
      AaBbCcDd

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}


